# Call to appendPixelBuffer of AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor Causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, avassetwriter

I am generating a CVPixelBufferRef from an OpenGL layer like this

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef) getGLPixelBuf {
    int s = 1;
    UIScreen * screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    if ([screen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]){
        s = (int)[screen scale];
    }
    const int w = self.frame.size.width/2;
    const int h = self.frame.size.height/2;
    const NSInteger my_data_length = 4 * w * h * s * s;
    // allocate array and read pixels into it.
    GLubyte * buffer = malloc(my_data_length);

    GLint readType;
    GLint readFormat;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE, &readType);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT, &readFormat);

    glReadPixels(0, 0, w * s, h * s, readFormat, readType, buffer);

    // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
    GLubyte * buffer2 = malloc(my_data_length);

    for(int y = 0; y < h*s; y++){
        memcpy(buffer2 + (h * s - 1 - y) * 4 * w * s, buffer + (4 * y * w * s), 4 * w * s);
    }

    free(buffer);
    CVPixelBufferRef pixel_buffer = NULL;
    CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes (NULL, w * 2, h * 2, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, buffer2 , 4 * w * s, NULL, 0, NULL, &pixel_buffer);
    free(buffer2);

    return pixel_buffer;
}
```

and then passing that pixel buffer to my a AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor inside a helper class like this:

```
- (void)recordFrame {
    if([recorder isRecording]){
        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [self getGLPixelBuf];
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

        [recorder appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:camera.lastSampleTime];

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
        CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
    }
}
```

however inside that helper class, the following

```
- (BOOL)appendPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:(CMTime)presentationTime {
    if (writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData)     
        return [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTime];  
    return NO;
}
```

causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I make the appendPixelBuffer call. I have enabled NSZombieEnabled but it's not providing me any information. The recorder is initialized to the same height and width as the backing heigh and width of the OpenGL layer. The adaptor is configured for kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA pixel format as well as the pixel buffer.

any help is appreciated! thanks!

Comment: have you checked with debugger and found the line it getting error  exactly?

Comment: the parameters which you send is of same object at called method ?

Comment: I have it working now. It appears as if my pixel buffer was falling out of context. I combined the two methods above into one, and I no longer receive the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: I'm having similar problem (where opengl seems to be falling on of context... i.e. all bytes in a buffer after a call to glReadPixels are 0.) However, if I try to append the pixel buffer within the main rendering loop then my call to appendPixelBuffer I get this error: -[NSCFNumber appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x64d0860 I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake somewhere, but I haven't come across any simple working example code writes a series of openGL textures (or renderbuffers) to a video file.

Comment: the problem is you're using free(buffer2); before using the pixel buffer which uses buffer2.

Answer (score 0):

Do not lock your pixel buffer when you append it to adaptor and your pixel_buffer returned by method `- (CVPixelBufferRef) getGLPixelBuf;` is not retained, to use  `CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);` in `- (void)recordFrame;` method you need to retain pixel_buffer before returned from `- (CVPixelBufferRef) getGLPixelBuf;`